# Increase Yellow Saturation only in RGB or HSV Image (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, computer-vision, hsv

I have an image. I want to selectively increase the saturation of yellow in the image to max. How is this done in the RGB or HSV image space? Thanks.

Comment: The original code you listed was riddled with errors unfortunately. I have now solved it though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This needs to be done in HSV (Hue **Saturation** Value) color space.

If you have the image in HSV, it is very easy (else convert it to HSV). The H is the only variable that gives color information, and if you check the wikipedia page of [Shades of Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_yellow), you'll notice they are all are between 45 to 60 deg. So take you HSV image, select the H in that range and increase the S (saturation) of those values.

In Matlab:

```
%Read image
imghsv=imread('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/34/6884934-yellow-flowers.jpg');
imghsv=rgb2hsv(im2double(imghsv));

%pick yellow
yellowIndex=repmat((imghsv(:,:,1)>45/360)&(imghsv(:,:,1)<60/360),[1 1 3]);   
yellow=imghsv.*yellowIndex;

%Saturate it
moreSaturation=2;
yellowsaturated=yellow(:,:,2)*moreSaturation;
yellow(:,:,2)=yellowsaturated;

%put it back
newHsv=imghsv; 
newHsv(yellowIndex)=yellow(yellowIndex);
```

result:

Original

[image]

Yellow pixels

[image]

Saturated

[image]